# How to return slope from OLS in statsmodels

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am fitting an OLS model using statsmodels. I need to return the slope of the fitted line.

```
model = sm.OLS(y, X)
results = model.fit()
```

`results.fittedvalues` gives me the points of the line. How to get the slope?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`results.params` contains the "slopes" for all the variables used.